# How can I load external json file in JSFiddle in ReactJs?

Tags: json, reactjs

I need to load a json file from Myjson in JSFiddle.I create a Myjson link `https://api.myjson.com/bins/34ds9` .I need to read data from that Json file .I'm very new in ReactJS.

Answer (score 1):

On your `componentDidMount()` you would just run an ajax call to get that data.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/34ds9",
    method: "GET"
  }).done((data) => {
    // Do whatever in here, set state, etc.
  });
}
```